# How to declare Transaction bean in spring in class based annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have declared the bean for the Transaction in my Config.java class as:

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

 @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new 
      DriverManagerDataSource();

   dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.5:1521:DCGCDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("OWNER");
        dataSource.setPassword("OWNER");

        return dataSource;
    }
```

but for xml based i have seen:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

Are these both the same or I am lacking something in my class based annotation?

In my pom.xml for transaction i have declared:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: do you have annotation config and xml config? I would suggest not to do it, choose one of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have annotation config and xml config? I would suggest NOT to do it, choose one of both. Appart of this, you are configuring two transaction managers (transactionManager and txManager). Remove declaration of txManager since the one you are going to use is transactionManager (this is the one that is going to give support to the @Transactional annotated methods)

further information can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)